# Is it possible the get the error of a previous try of a task in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have a task that is configured to retry 3 times. I would like to perform some logic if the exception of the original failure is of a certain type. Is it possible from run 2 of the task for example, to extract the exception from the first attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an exiting method to read the log/error for an other task or an older try for the same task, because these data are not saved in the metadata.

But where the log files are saved in local/remote storage, you can read the log file of the previous try and parse it to get the error:

```
previous_try_log_filename = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ ti.try_number }}.log
```

But you need to check if the `{{ ti.try_number }} != "1"` to skip this step in the first try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on_retry_callback` which is invoked when the task is up for retry in order to retrieve the exception raised by each failure and perform some logic according to your needs.

Example dag :

```
import airflow
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def task_retry(context):
    ti = context['task_instance']
    exception = context['exception']
    # your logic using exception and task_instance attributes (ti.task_id, ti.dag_id, ti.operator, ti.log_url...)
    # attributes of task_instance are listed here : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html


def example_function():
    raise ValueError('A very specific bad thing happened.')


with airflow.DAG(
        dag_id='example_dag',
        default_args={
            "depends_on_past": False,
            "retries": 3,
            "retry_delay": timedelta(60),
            "start_date": datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(1), datetime.min.time()),
            "on_retry_callback": task_retry,
        },
        schedule_interval=None
) as dag:
    example_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='example_task',
        python_callable=example_function,
        provide_context=True,
    )
```